# Sampling Gaussian Distribution, how to understand the formula?

Tags: probability, statistics

To generate a sample according to Gaussian distribution, it follows an algorithms such that

$\frac{1}{2}\sum_\limits{1}^{12}rand(-b, b)$, where rand function is to generate a sample uniformly on certain interval.

How should we understand the formula ? why running exactly 12 times and why divided by 2 ?

Comment: Not accurate. But the sum of "enough" independent identically distributed "nice" random variables has roughly normal distribution, and the person advocating this algorithm considers $12$ enough.

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$and also, it makes the standard deviation equal to $b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variance of a random variable that is uniformly distributed between $-b$ and $b$ is $b^2/3$.  The variance of the sum of $12$ of those is is $12$ times that, thus $4b^2$. That variance of half of *that* is therefore $b^2$.  So $12$ is how many it takes to make the standard deviation equal to $b$.  And $12$ is enough that the distribution is close enough to Gaussian to satisfy the person proposing this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have the reference paper for this formula ? Or does this formula have a name of notation in mathematics ?

Comment: @XingdongZuo : Probably many textbooks assign as an exercise the proof that the variance of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is $1/12$  For the interval $[0,c]$,it's just rescaled, so the variance is just multiplied by $c^2$ and you get $c^2/12$.  For the interval $[a,b]$, that merely a relocation of the interval $[0,b-a]$, so the variance is the same as for that interval, i.e. $(b-a)^2/12$.  Here we're looking at the case where $a=-b$. But you could just compute the variance from scratch by evaluating an integral. ${}\qquad{}$